# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: entiy is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this error when I startup wildflu 20, this deployment is a service.jar(EJB project), well this error y logging to all Entity declare in namedquery.
I'm think that error is trigger bacause my jpa Annotation in all Entity is not loading by hibernate 5.3.

All my entity look like hibernate dont know it, these are listed in persistense.xml and each class has @annotation jpa.

Other point, if I build ear file this and load without problem and ear project is deployed fine.

The namedquery hibernate dont know when wildfly 20 startup
What could I went do wrong??

Comment: Please add minimal code to reproduce this issue to help you.

Comment: Hi @Eklavya, more that code I think that error is in desing component or something in wildfly that prevent this model, I have EJB project with service JNIDI and soap, and Entity is inside of other project lid in .jar file, I put that in Deployment assembly. But when I startup ejb projects alone dont load any Entity JPA Annotation from lib project

Comment: Now @Eklavya, I deployed ejb project but with other strategy, 1. I did a Entreprise application 2. push ejb module and lib (Entities jpa anotation class) in deploiment assembly and walla all right.  I'll hope let put out the lib like wildfly modules with entities to manage future version, cant I do it that?